# PHP - Cache Control is not working in my scenario

Tags: php

i need some help, i got a php file which is called shoppingcart.php and the data of chosen product will post to this page for sql insert, and if i reload this page by f5 or press "Backspace" at next page, the same data will re-insert again so i don't want this to happen and been doing some searching but still not solving my problem.

My Code:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["form"])){
//insert data to db
}

ob_start();
?>

<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"
enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate();">
....
....
....
</form>

<?php
$pagecontent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$pagetitle = "Shopping Cart";
include("include/template.php");
?>
```

I have researched on output buffer and http header article but i still can't figure it out why it is still happening. Please help me~ Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear where you're setting the Cache-control header. Read up on RFC 2616 to understand Cache-control.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time asking question here, i didn't notice the first few lines wasn't display.

Comment: did you check the page header returned ?

Comment: and are you sure that you are sending the `header` before any php or html output ?

Comment: ya i got check with headers_sent() func after this line "header("Pragma: no-cache");" and the header is not send. Beside that i tried flush() after the same line to send the header but i still can't get it work. The request header list don't have cache-control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting all your Cache-control headers into the same call to `header()`. The browser may not be expecting multiple Cache-control headers.

Also, are you getting a prompt in the browser that reloading will resubmit POST data? If so, and you are electing to resubmit, you will need your own code to ensure that force-rePOSTed data is rejected (despite the user's request), eg. by including a unique identifier in the form that is checked before re-inserting. Alternatively you can accept that if the user elects to resubmit POST data, then they are explicitly requesting that the request be re-processed.